# Unable to get result while returning value from the function in PHP

Tags: php, function, file, directory, glob

I am unable to get the desired result with this PHP code.

I have a folder named audio in which there are 2 mp3 files as in picture [Audio folder contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XghHR.png)

And i have kept the singers name in shortform in mp3 files like RI for RIHANA and MC for MILEY CYRUS.

The thing is I want the code that scans the audio folder and checks for the playlist and finds the mp3 files according to playlist and songnumber selected. Then it will show the SINGERS NAME AVAILABLE in full form (I have made a separete function for that also) but i am unable to get SINGERS FULL NAME. It repeatedly gives the same singer name for all the different audio files that are available in folder named audio. It gives short name accurate but not the full name. You can see that in the pic. [Result of PHP code when executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PISt.png)

So Please help me with this.

And main thing is I need THE RESULT OUTSIDE THE FUNCTION. NOT INSIDE AS I HAVE DONE.

[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXx3U.png)

```
<?php
# a slightly modified version of the original function
    function singeractualname( $ssn ) {
        switch( $ssn ){
            case 'MC':return 'Miley Cyrus';
            case 'RI':return 'Rihanna';
            default:return 'Singer name not available !!!';
        }
    }
    function outputFiles( $path, $song, $dir ){
        $output=[];
        if( file_exists( realpath( $path ) ) ){
            
            $dirItr=new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $path, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::KEY_AS_PATHNAME );
            
            foreach( new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $dirItr, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST ) as $obj => $info ) {
                if( $info->isFile() ){
                    
                    $pttn=sprintf( '@%s-\w+\.\w+@i', $song );
                    preg_match( $pttn, $info->getFileName(), $col );

                    if( !empty( $col ) ){
                        foreach( $col as $file ){
                            
                            $ext=pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
                            list( $int, $cat, $code )=explode( '-', pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_FILENAME ) );
                            
                            $output[]=(object)[
                                'ext'       =>  $ext,
                                'code'      =>  $code,
                                'name'      =>  singeractualname( $code ),
                                'file'      =>  $dir . '/' . $info->getFileName(),
                                'index'     =>  $int,
                                'category'  =>  $cat
                            ];                          
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        array_unshift( $output, (object)[
            'ext'       =>  'html',
            'code'      =>  false,
            'name'      =>  'Home',
            'file'      =>  '/homepage.html',
            'index'     =>  false,
            'category'  =>  false
        ]);
        
        return $output;
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    $PlaylistName = 'ROCK';
    $songNumber = 1;
    
    $root='';
    $dir='audio';
    
    $path=$root . $dir;
    $song=sprintf( '%s-%s', $songNumber, $PlaylistName );
    
    
    $arr=outputFiles( $path, $song, $dir );
    
    
    foreach( $arr as $obj ) {
        printf(
            '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="audio/css/main.css"><div class="wrap-login100 p-l-85 p-r-85 p-t-55 p-b-55"><br><br><audio width="100%" height="100%" controls="controls" src="%1$s" controlslist="nodownload" type="audio/mp3" style="visibility: visible;">
</audio><br /><font size="4" color="#000080"><b>Singer : <font size="4" color="#B22222">%2$s</b></font></font></div>',
            $obj->file,
            $obj->name
        );
    }
```

Comment: `if ($singershortname = "MC")` that's assigning a value. To compare, use two or three equal signs: `if ($singershortname == "MC")`. So what happens here is that you assign the variable the value to "MC" in the first if, which will always evaluate as true (since it's a truthy value) and your `elseif` and `else` will never be executed. You also pass in `$shortname` while comparing `$singershortname` so it should really be: `if ($shortname == 'MC')` and `elseif ($shortname == 'RI')`

Comment: Sir can you plz edit the function and write it clearly for me, what the exact function should be. I am not getting you Please........ The thing is i need a function that gives full name for the short code that the function generates for the singer name from audio file name

Comment: I'm just talking about your function `singeractualname()`. To assign a variable a value, you do `$variable = 'value';` (one `=`). To _compare_ a value, you do `$variable == 'value'` (two `==` or three `===`). So in you `if`-statements in your function, you're not _comparing_ the variable with the value, you're _assigning_ the variable a value. Also, your function signature is `function singeractualname($shortname)` which means that it's the `$shortname` variable you need to use in your function, not `$singershortname`.

Comment: Thankyou sir!! It worked now :) But sir one more thing i wanna ask is how can i generate a html( with hyperlink to mp3 file) with those singers name generated??

Comment: Not sure I follow you, but if t he question is how to get the name as a link to a file instead, then do: `$singerfullname = '<a href="link-to-mp3">Miley Cyrus</a>';` and the same for the other artist. If you now echo that variable on a page, it will be a link.

Comment: In the screenshot there are only 2 files, in reality I'd imagine there will be many more. Will these files always follow the same naming convention - `number-cat-shortcode.ext` etc?

Comment: yes these files always follow the same naming convention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return a list of all files found and you are hoping to recursively navigate through folders and sub-folders there needs to be, with the above code, some means of storing details for all files found which can be returned from this function. Rather than attempt to manually recurse directories and maintain a list of files found you  might consider using one of the native PHP `recursiveIterator` type classes.

If the format of the songs remains in a constant format you might consider a simpler method to tokenize the filename - `list` combined with `explode` allow for very easy naming of these tokens and with one of these tokens you can perform the lookup to find the full name. A `regEx` would be more flexible if the format were to vary between artists/directories - but the pattern below would need considerable refinement perhaps ;-)

```
# a slightly modified version of the original function
    function singeractualname( $ssn ) {
        switch( $ssn ){
            case 'MC':return 'Miley Cyrus';
            case 'RI':return 'Rihanna';
            default:return 'Singer name not available !!!';
        }
    }
    function outputFiles( $path, $song, $dir ){
        $output=[];
        if( file_exists( realpath( $path ) ) ){
            
            $dirItr=new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $path, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::KEY_AS_PATHNAME );
            
            foreach( new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $dirItr, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST ) as $obj => $info ) {
                if( $info->isFile() ){
                    
                    $pttn=sprintf( '@%s-\w+\.\w+@i', $song );
                    preg_match( $pttn, $info->getFileName(), $col );

                    if( !empty( $col ) ){
                        foreach( $col as $file ){
                            
                            $ext=pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
                            list( $int, $cat, $code )=explode( '-', pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_FILENAME ) );
                            
                            $output[]=(object)[
                                'ext'       =>  $ext,
                                'code'      =>  $code,
                                'name'      =>  singeractualname( $code ),
                                'file'      =>  $dir . '/' . $info->getFileName(),
                                'index'     =>  $int,
                                'category'  =>  $cat
                            ];                          
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        array_unshift( $output, (object)[
            'ext'       =>  'html',
            'code'      =>  false,
            'name'      =>  'Home',
            'file'      =>  '/homepage.html',
            'index'     =>  false,
            'category'  =>  false
        ]);
        
        return $output;
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    $PlaylistName = 'ROCK';
    $songNumber = 1;
    
    $root='c:/wwwroot';
    $dir='/sfx/mp3/tmp';
    
    $path=$root . $dir;
    $song=sprintf( '%s-%s', $songNumber, $PlaylistName );
    
    
    $arr=outputFiles( $path, $song, $dir );
    
    
    foreach( $arr as $obj ) {
        printf(
            '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s">%2$s</a><br />',
            $obj->file,
            $obj->name
        );
    }
```

Given a similar directory and content
[image: Directory and files]

The output would be

```
<a href="/homepage.html" title="Home">Home</a><br />
<a href="/sfx/mp3/tmp/1-ROCK-ACDC.mp3" title="Singer name not available !!!">Singer name not available !!!</a><br />
<a href="/sfx/mp3/tmp/1-ROCK-MC.mp3" title="Miley Cyrus">Miley Cyrus</a><br />
<a href="/sfx/mp3/tmp/1-ROCK-RI.mp3" title="Rihanna">Rihanna</a><br />
```

Comment: <a href="1-ROCK-RI.mp3" title="Rihanna">Rihanna</a><br /> The php generates the hyperlink with file location in working directory. But actually the audio files are in AUDIO folder. So how to make it like <a href="../audio/1-ROCK-RI.mp3".... AND also tell me how to insert a hyperink <a href="homepage.html" title="Homepage">Navigate to Homepage</a><br /> so that user can go back to homepage from there without pressing back button on browser

Comment: Sir I dont know from where you got that result?? I am just getting home button with this code

Comment: If you look at the code I posted it has `$root='c:/wwwroot';` and `$dir='/sfx/mp3/tmp';` which are relevant to my system... I thought you'd take that into account and edit to suit your environment.

Comment: Everything is fine except this https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXx3U.png I need Home as a button not a audio file. I have modified the code to latest plz have a look

Comment: just add the homepage link manually before you call the php function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62810518/issue-with-the-code-while-generating-actual-file-in-php sir plz see this if u can help me little more plzzzzz

Comment: I don't see that there is a problem. If you remove, from the above `array_unshift()` you can manually add your homepage link and leave the php function to properly find files and generate the respective hyperlink.